# Does this series converge: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (\cos \frac1n)^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I have a series defined like this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\cos \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

and I need to find out whether it converges or diverges. I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 1$ but does it tell something about the series when the sign is alternating?

Comment: $a_n\to 0 \iff |a_n|\to 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An infinite series $\sum\limits_{n} a_n$ will *never* converge if $a_n \not\to 0$. It doesn't matter if it is alternating or not.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this holds.

Comment: You're welcome. See for example on Wikipedia [Term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: @Gogis It's true, and fairly easy to show (it also makes pretty good exercise)

Answer (score 1):

The original series diverges, as you end-up subtracting then adding $1$.

Anyway, by grouping the terms in pairs, you get a new series with the general term

$$\left(\cos\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right)^{2n}-\left(\cos\left(\frac1{2n+1}\right)\right)^{2n+1}\\
=\left(1-\frac1{2(2n)^2}+\cdots\right)^{2n}-\left(1-\frac1{2(2n+1)^2}+\cdots\right)^{2n+1}\\
=1-\frac{2n}{8n^2}+\cdots-1+\frac{2n+1}{2(2n+1)^2}-\cdots\\
\approx-\frac1{2n(2n+1)}=\Theta\left(\frac1{n^2}\right),$$

which does converge, I guess.